# Understanding stratified K fold cross validation results (for LSTM binary classification model)

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, validation

I am performing a Binary Classification task with LSTMs.

Data_size `(205, 100, 4)` 
- Out of 205 samples `110 belongs to class 0` & `95 belongs to Class 1`, all data were shuffled inside a list.

```
train_test_split : (train : 85 % & test : 15 % , random_seed = 7)
Fixed train data shape = (174,100,6)
Fixed test Data = (31,100,6)
```

**MODEL TRAINING**

I trained my LSTM model

1.1) for model Structure [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/992Vf.jpg)

1.2) for Acc & Loss graph (both train & Validate) [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NR9D.jpg) 
**– No Overfitting observed**

1.3) Prediction result : 3 out of 31 testing data were wrong.
(91 % correct prediction)

**1st STRATIFIED K FOLD CROSS VALIDATION (CV)**

2.1) Fold – 7 ; random seed = 7 ; data_size = (205,100,6)

2.2) Plot `acc & loss` graph for every folds. Some **folds results in Over fitting** [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP0gG.jpg)

2.3) Calculated accuracy for every fold and mean acc value is `79.46 % (+/- 5.60 %)`

**2nd STRATIFIED K fold Cross Validation (CV)**

Changed the `model structure by reducing the units/neurons in the layers` and performed 7 fold CV again with same data size

3.1) Acc and loss plot. Only some folds were over fitted [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UofRY.jpg)

3.2) Calculated accuracy for every fold and mean acc value is `79.00 % (+/- 3.81 %)`

**Questions**

Q.1) Is that fine to chose 7 folds arbitrarily or should i go for 10 folds ?
Will that make any difference ?

Q.2) Is there any limit, `if my mean acc value should be > than some %`, is considered as a good performing model where the hyper parameters chosen is the best ?

Q.3) On `comparing 1st and 2nd CV results`, 2nd CV results outperforms 
1st CV in std deviation but my mean acc is almost common. Also, prediction accuracy is good for model 1 than model 2. In that case, which model hyper parameters should i fix as final ?

Q.4) My friend suggested me to try LOOCV, but will that make any difference ?